# How to sort an array and then save to database in Android

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of numbers, then take the output to save it to my database.  Any help would be appreciated, thank!  I can sometimes get the sort to work, but I'm having trouble accessing the array to get specific numbers to then save.

```
Integer[] toSortArray = {saveInt1, saveInt2, saveInt3, saveInt4, saveInt5};

Arrays.toString(new Integer[]{toSortArray[2]})
```

Comment: What would be the point of sorting ? If you save these values to database then you can retrieve them in sorted order.

Comment: Solid point, but, essentially just to keep consistency throughout my database design (good or bad is another question).  I'll incoming non user saved data is currently saved in numerical order.

Comment: Regardless of db system you use (sql, oracle, mongo, etc) there is no guarantee your db will return your data in the order you save them. So this array sorting is pointless and instead of doing it you just need to explicitly specify the order in your query (e.g "ORDER BY " in sql) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sort, just do

```
Arrays.sort(toSortArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data to database in any order but you can retrieve those in sorted order using query below.

```
"SELECT * from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY COL_NAME ASC/DESC;"
```